# about QT Tcpserver and Thread

Tags: c++, qt

i try to run a tcpserver in subThread,
so i write a workerClass

```cpp
/**here is head file(simple version)**/
class serverWorker : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  serverWorker(QObject* parent = nullptr);

public slots:
  void setTcpServer();

  void startListen(int port);
private:
  QTcpServer* server;
  
  QQTcpSocket* clientSocket;

private slots:
  void setUpNewConnect();

}
```

```cpp
/**here is sourse file**/
void serverWOrker::setTcpServer()
{
  server = new QTcpServer;
  connect(server,&QTcpServer::newConnection,
          this,&serverWorker::setUpConnection);
}

void serverWorker::setUpConnection()
{
  clientSocket = server->nextPendingConnection();
  connect(clientSocket,&QTcpSocket::readyRead,[=](){
    clientSocket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
    auto data = clientSocket->readAll();
  });
}

void serverWorker::startListen(int port)
{
  server->listen(QHostAddress::Any,port);//to here it`s broken
}
```

in MianThread i used a signal to trigger startListen function

it`s just broken

so where i made mistake?

or

how can i run a tcpserver in subThread.

/**update**/

in mainThread

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) 
  ：QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  serverWorker* worker = new serverWorker();

  QThread* subTHread = new QThread(this);

  worker->moveToThread(subTHread);

  subThread->start();

  connect(this,SIGNAL(triggerSetupTcpServer()),
          worker,SLOT(setTcpServer()));

  connect(this,SIGNAL(startListen(int)),
           worker,SLOT(startListen(int)));

  connect(ui->button,&QPushButton::clicked,[=](){
            emit(startListen(ui->spinBox->value()));
          });

  emit(triggerSetupTcpServer);
}
```

when i clicked button try startListen;

my program will shutdown;

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] -- the code shown doesn't create any new threads.  Also, please explain what you mean by `"it's just broken"`.

Comment: Did you move worker to a thread, did you start the thread? Why do you `waitForReadyRead` inside `readyRead` slot? By the way, you dont have to use threads if you are not using blocking functions like `waitForReadyRead`, you can do everything in main thread.

Comment: @G.M. buddy i update this question , can you see again , thanks.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows i update the question , maybe my account puzzle you,can you see again , thanks

Comment: Which debugging have you done so far? In the line in which it crashes on your account, have you checked if that is really the culprit line? That is, have you surrounded it by debugging output? If yes, I'd assume that for *some* reason, `server` is a null pointer. Pretty much everything else should cause a proper error message. Print the address of `server` before you call `listen`. Also, create a debugging output in `setTcpServer`, possibly also with the address of `server`. The signals look fine, but maybe that method is not properly called for some reason.